# Dirac delta function + constant

Tags: dirac-delta

If we sum the Dirac delta function with a constant, what is the result?
I.e., $k+\delta(x)$, where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: Think about the values that the Delta function takes on over the real line and at $x=0$.

Comment: something like: $+\infty$ when $x=0$ and $0$ in everywhere else?

Comment: The Dirac delta isn't a function. That being said, I don't see why anything special at all would happen. $\delta(x) + k$ is just $\delta(x) + k$, and that's it.

Comment: I would like to plot the result and I would like to know whether $k+\delta(x)\approx k$ is correct

Comment: I agree with @Arthur , $\delta +k$ is the functional on the space of test functions $\varphi$ such that $\langle \delta +k,\varphi\rangle=\varphi(0)+k$ or the measure such that $\int \varphi d(\delta +k)=\int\varphi d\delta +k$

Comment: @PeterMelech No, $<\delta +k,\phi>$ should be $\phi(0)=k\int\phi$. (It certainly can't  be $\phi(0)+k$; that's not linear in $\phi$.)

Comment: @DavidUllrich This means that the right answer is $\delta (x)+k=k$ since $\phi=1$

Comment: @David Sure that wouldn't be a functional, You're right. And then what is $k\delta$ ?

Comment: @ARF Huh??? That doesn't make any sense that II can see

Comment: @PeterMelech The pairing is linear : $<k\delta,\phi>=k\phi(0)$.

Comment: @David I see, that makes sense

Comment: @David How possible $k \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi=\phi(0)$?

Comment: @ARF Why do  you imagine that $k\int\phi=\phi(0)$ follows from anything I said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion here. The "delta function" is sometimes treated "informally", as though it were a function with the property that $$\int f(x)\delta(x)=f(0)$$for all $f$. There may be some merit to such an "informal" presentation in some contexts, but in fact it's wrong; there is no such function.

$\newcommand\D{\mathcal D}$

If we want to get this straight we alas *need* to start with a more formally correct definition. First, $\D$ is the space of all infinitely differentiable functions with compact support. A *distribution* is a map $u:\D\to\Bbb R$ such that (i) $u$ is linear (ii) $u$ is continuous.

Explaining exactly what it means to say $u$ is continuous gets a little complicated. We don't need to get that straight here, we just do need to keep in mind that a distribution is *not* a function (ie not a function defined on the line), rather a distribution is a certain sort of linear mapping from $\D$ to $\Bbb R$.

The space of distributions is denoted $\D'$. So if $u\in\D'$ and $\phi\in\D$ then $$u(\phi)\in\Bbb R.$$The notation $$<u,\phi>:=u(\phi)$$is often convenient.

If $f$ is a (locally integrable) function on $\Bbb R$ then $f$ may be regarded as a distribution; here the distribution corresponding to the function $f$ is defined by $$<f,\phi>=\int f\phi.$$(Where $\int$ means $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.)

If $u$and $v$ are distributions and $k$ is a constant then the distributions $u+v$ and $ku$  are defined by $$<u+v,\phi>=<u,\phi>+<v,\phi>$$and $$<ku,\phi>=k<u,\phi>.$$

And the distibution $\delta$ is defined by $$<\delta,\phi>=\phi(0).$$

And now we can answer the question of what $\delta+k$ is if $k$ is a constant. Here we regard $k$ as a constant *function*; so applying the definitions above gives $$<\delta+k,\phi>=<\delta,\phi>+<k,\phi>=\phi(0)+\int k\phi=\phi(0)+k\int\phi\quad(\phi\in\D).$$

That really is all there is to be said; $<\delta+k,\phi>=\phi(0)=k\int\phi$ really is the *definition* of $\delta+k$. Honest.

Not the answer you wanted? Sorry, nothing to be done about that. How would we *plot* $\delta+k$? We *don't* "plot" $\delta+k$; that makes no sense, because $\delta+k$ is not a function.